# how to use navigation bar in ios 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I want to add navigation bar in IOS 7.0  with add bar button item on that. So please suggest how to add navigation bar in IOS application.

```
UIButton *btnBack=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aerrow-previous.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnBack setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"aerrow-previous.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[btnBack setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btnBack setFrame:CGRectMake(5, 5, 20, 21)];
[btnBack addTarget:self action:@selector(backBtnPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *leftBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btnBack];
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:leftBarButton];
btnBack = nil;
leftBarButton = nil;
// Add back button on navigation bar


UILabel *titileview=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 44)];


[titileview setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(87.0f/255.0f) green:(87.0f/255.0f) blue:(87.0f/255.0f) alpha:1.0f]];
[titileview setText:@"SIGN IN"];
[titileview setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[titileview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationItem setTitleView:titileview];
titileview = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code similar to this one:

```
UIBarButtonItem *addBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addObject:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightButton];
```

Hope it helps!